# Cocos2d-X animation blinking red

Tags: c++, animation, cocos2d-x

When i start an Animation (using the code below), allof the sprites.png's are misscolored (red) except for the starting picture, so it looks like it's blinking red.
I wondered if anyone know what causes this?
I use TexturePacker to make the sprite sheet, with the settings: Pixel Format: RGBA8888, Texture Format: PVR+zlib.
Here is the code for my animation, which I have in my Player class and it's iniated when it's created:

```
FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchResolutionsOrder("indian_spreedsheet/HD");
// load and cache the texture and sprite frames
auto cacher = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
cacher->addSpriteFramesWithFile("indian_walk.plist");

#include <sstream>
// load all the animation frames into an array
const int kNumberOfFrames = 4;
Vector<SpriteFrame*> frames;
for (int i = 1; i < kNumberOfFrames; i++)
{
    std::string s = std::to_string( i );

    SpriteFrame* aFrame =
    cacher->getSpriteFrameByName( "indian_walk" + s + ".png" );
    frames.pushBack(aFrame);
}

// play the animation
auto animation = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(frames, 0.40f);
animation->setRestoreOriginalFrame(true);
moveAnimate = Animate::create(animation);
moveAnimate->retain();
```

I work in Visual Studio, with Cocos2d-x version 3.3.
I can include pictures of the event if anyone feel it's needed.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your "indian_walk.png", is there some red color on it?

as described in the official document:

> Is there a trial version?
>
> Yes, there is a 7-day trial mode with
> unrestricted features. After that period TexturePacker goes into
> Essential mode. It is restricted to basic features. If you use Pro
> features in this mode, you will get a warning before publishing and
>
> **some of your sprites will turn red in the output.**

link is [here](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/support)

Comment: I use red in indian_walk.png, I'm not sure if the spreed sheet is red colored as I don't know how to open .plist files.

I see, I have missed that comment nor any warning before I published.
This seem like a very reasonable explanation though, I will try to use some other program or buy it and see if it fixes it. 

Thank you!